# As a Neutral-Good character, how greedy can I be?

Tags: roleplaying, alignment, metagaming

I'm trying to play a neutral good wizard, but recently I came across a large sum of gold while adventuring with the party. Now, some members of the party screwed me out of gold in the past, but in this case, we were adventuring together - the other members only know about the gold meta wise. It's also important to mention that I'm the poorest member of the party, and bought something on credit before hand, but even that only through the gold given to me by one of the other party members. And, of course, there are some members of the party with whom I disagree with. Also, no matter what happens, my first thing will be to pay off my debts.

I'm really at a loss at what to do - keep the gold, keep most of the gold, or share it evenly.

Comment: This seems very subject to opinion, but a large part of that is because the alignment system is very open to interpretation. Expect recommendations to drop it altogether.

Comment: This question is rooted in getting subjective observations of the D&D alignment system. I've closed it because interpretations are so varied that the only people you can ask are the rest of your party.

Comment: ...And your GM.

Comment: But do try taking a look at our other questions tagged [tag:alignment], many of them may help you and your group answer this question for yourselves.

Comment: Actually, taking a look, I see [this question](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/24931/4563), which is extremely similar (and should have been closed for the same reasons this was). You’ll see, for example, exactly what @LitheOhm said: recommendations to drop alignment altogether.